# Escape if statement in C

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){    
    double array1[8] = {0};    
    double data;    
    double lg_data=0;    
    int i = 0, j = 0;    
    int count = 1;    
    int lg_count = 1;    

    printf("7개의 양의 실수를 입력하세요.(마지막 원소는 자동으로 -1이 됩니다.)\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if (i == 7){
            array1[i] = -1;
        }
        else{
            scanf("%lf", &array1[i]);
        }
    }//end of loop
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        count = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (array1[i] == array1[j]){
                count++;
                if (count >= lg_count){
                    lg_count = count;
                    data = array1[i];
                    if (data >= lg_data){
                        lg_data = data;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if (array1[i] >= lg_data){
                    lg_data = array1[i];
                    lg_count = count;
                }
            }
        }//end of for(j)
    }//end of for(i)
    printf("%lf %d\n", lg_data, lg_count);
    return;
```

If there are values that agree with  `if (array1[i] == array1[j])` statement, I want to stop for loop even though still have values that agree with else statement. I already tried to put break statement inside if statement ... but it didn't work. 
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: you can use GOTO functions

Comment: Do you want to stop the inner loop or the outer loop?  Inner loop, use break, outer loop use break and flags or goto.

Comment: Is your question about the inner or the outer `for` loop? `break` should work fine to terminate the inner `for` loop. To terminate the outer, just set a flag in the `if` block and check the flag in the outer `for` loop.

Comment: I want to stop outer loop. what is flag? and how can i use flag or goto?

Comment: There are lots of solutions in this thread. Just a hint: as it is a poor programming style, please do _not_ use a goto.

Comment: @buffo: Using `goto`s to break out of nested loops is one of the few legitimate uses for them. Yes, if the nested loops are sufficiently complex you should consider factoring them out into a function (so you can just break out of them by `return`-ing), but ruling out `goto` is a knee jerk reflex drilled into CS students (much like admonitions to only have one `return` per function) that isn't always the best solution in the real world.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I  partially agree (and I never attended any CS course ;-)). As I can tell from my experience, preventing any `goto` s (and only one `return` per function) highly increasing the persistence of the source code. So I should correct myself to: as it is `often` poor programming style, please `consider` where to use a `goto` (as there are solutions where they are handy).

Comment: Btw, "*it didn't work*" is one of the worth error description possible.

Answer (score 1):

The [break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx) statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing `do`, `for`, `switch`, or `while` statement in which it appears.

Look at the following example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
        break; // this will break loop "j"
               // whereas loop "i" will still iterate
    }
}
```

So if you want to stop both loops, you may do this:

```
flag = false;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if(condition == TRUE_FOR_BREAK) {
            flag = true;
            break; // "j" loop break
        }
    }
    if(flag) {
        break; // "i" loop break
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I put in a request to just use `if (flag) {`? Testing equality with `true` and `false` is kind of awful; if it's `== true`, then it's already `true`!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split the two nested loops into a separate function. By returning from the function, execution will escape the two for loops:

```
void loops() {
   for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        count = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
          if (array1[i] == array1[j]){
              ...
              return;
              ...
          }
        }
    }

}

...
loops()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break` keyword to exit out of the closest inner loop. However, if you have additional loops outside of that inner loop, you'll need to set a variable to a specific value and make sure all your outer loops always check this variable and exit the loop when it is set to that value.

Answer (score 0):

put this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        count = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (array1[i] == array1[j]){
                count++;
                if (count >= lg_count){
                    lg_count = count;
                    data = array1[i];
                    if (data >= lg_data){
                        lg_data = data;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if (array1[i] >= lg_data){
                    lg_data = array1[i];
                    lg_count = count;
                }
            }
        }//end of for(j)
    }//end of for(i)
```

in separate function and put return after condition if (array1[i] == array1[j]). If you are using VS you can use 'Extract method' options.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `break`

EG:

```
for(int i = 0; i<50;i++)
{
    if(i==10)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

this should iterate untill i euqals 10, then break out of the loop

Comment: He's got nested loops, so that doesn't do it on its own. Also, `i = 0; i > 50`??? The loop will never enter.

Comment: yup you rright,  i typo'd,  was mean to be i<50   was just a quick example loop of how the functionality works.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is aware of `break`.

Comment: actually he edited his post to say that after i mentioned it,  which is also why other people have said the same thing i have,  downvoting us for that is rather rude.

Comment: So what keeps you from adjusting your answer as well? It's "buggy" anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `break;` statement if you want to stop the execution of nearest loop statement.

Consider this code snippet:

```
int i =1;
while (true) {
    i++;
        if (i == 5) {
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is aware of `break`.

Comment: How come this answer does not answer OP's question? OP is asking on how to stop his looping condition, that's why I came up with this solution: using break statement. If OP is aware of break statement, he shouldn't ask the question then.

Comment: As per the OP's question: "*I already tried to put break statement inside ...*". The issue is that *only one* `break` wouldn't do, but that's exaclty what you propose.

Comment: Maybe I don't see break on his code. That's why I conclude that OP is unaware of break. Okay, my bad. Thanks buddy ;)